# How to create chainable class methods in PHP

Tags: php, function, class

I need help in PHP to create multi-dimensional classes and functions.

I need to call function like this:

```
 $app = new class1();
 $app->function1()->subfunction1()->subfunclevel2();
```

I've many variants but nothing seems to work.

In Javascript, I would create methods like this:

```
 (function($){
    function class1(){
        var function1 = function(){
             var subfunction1 = function(){

              };
        };
    };
 });
```

so this we will call like this:

```
 $.class1.function1.subfunction1();
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this with PHP.

Comment: Javascript's `class.function1.subfunction2` syntax does not actually invoke the function `function1`, instead it takes advantage of how "Properties" work in EMCAScript. PHP's object properties do not work in the same way.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to achieve is not an example of a "multidimensional" class or function.

Comment: PHP classes and methods don't work the way you think they do. You can't do what you're asking in PHP, nor can I see why you would want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking is for method chaining? You can return a reference to the object in each function to do this.

```
class class1
{
  public function method1()
  {
    echo "method1";
    return $this;
  }

  public function method2()
  {
    echo "method2";
    return $this;
  }
}

$class1_inst = new class1();
$class1_inst->method1()->method2(); // method1method2
```